# CRM 2011 sdk - obtaining count of entities without retrieving rows of data

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am using the CRM 2011 SDK to work with a remote CRM 2011 service. I need to retrieve the total number of contacts, which is something over 20000.

I've tried a simple LINQ query, eg. `Aggregate c In service.ContactSet Into Count()` (from [these examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918069.aspx), also [this suggestion](http://www.crmcodex.com/2012/01/using-linq-to-get-a-record-count-in-mscrm-2011/) and [this suggestion](http://rostacik.net/2011/08/11/how-to-get-count-of-entities-in-microsoft-crm-2011/)) but each one took *ages*, because the resulting XML that gets downloaded is an entire recordset of data (even if it's only the GUID, that's still 20000 GUIDs and all their XML fluff).

I can't seem to find how to simply query CRM 2011 in such a way as it returns *a single number* - the total count of records in an entity. A "scalar query" so to speak. How is this done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, LINQ queries does not support aggregates and grouping.

The documentation says:

> FetchXML Supports all the features of QueryExpression plus
>   **aggregates** and grouping. Queries are built as XML statements.

So, the only option you have is using FetchXML as follow:

```
string fetchQuery = @"<fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical' aggregate='true'> 
   <entity name='entity name'> 
      <attribute name='attribute name' aggregate='count' alias='aliasName'/> 
   </entity> 
</fetch>";

EntityCollection value = _serviceProxy.Execute(new FetchExpression(fetchQuery));
```

Returned result will be something as follow:

```
<resultset morerecords="0"'> 
   <result>
      <aliasName>20</aliasName>
   </result>
</resultset>
```

Comment: Many thanks! Now that I know the word "fetchxml" a whole new world has opened up on Google. :)